# I need to show channel entries in four columns and multiple rows ordered by latest entry first

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I need to show channel entries in the form of a grid. The grid has four columns and five rows. Therefore I show the first 20 entries. I need to use pagination to show the next 20 entries. I am not able to think of how to accomplish this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use  modulus operator  to split entries by columns/rows and then use pagination. Or use channel:entries offset parameter to get next 20 entries.

Comment: Why would the normal pagination parameter on an exp:channel:entries tag pair not do exactly this?

Comment: I would have loved to do it, just that I am extremely new to expressionengine and I am trying to learn as I go. An example to show the same would be of much help to me. Thanks

Comment: The requirement is such that there is a chosen template (Candidates - themeforest) which provides a 3 column template in divs. I need to figure out how to get the channel entries in those columns. Also, I dont want to use entry id since this is a blog in a grid view, and someone could have deleted a blog entry. it can tend to leave empty spaces if a particular id isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use for the [paginate parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html) on the channel:entries tag

As a very simple example...

```
... start the table ...
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo" paginate="bottom" limit="20"}
    <tr>
        <td>{title}</td><td>{another_field}</td><td>{yet_another_field}</td
    </tr>
    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
... close the table ...
```

EE will show a maximum of 20 rows and handle all the pagination for you

EDIT: From re-reading the question I see that you would be showing more than 1 entry per "row". Hence the answer referencing the modulus calculations.

Another way you might want to do it is to forgo the table completely (is a table the most appropriate element?) and use another HTML element that you can float across the page.

Comment: Or use CSS columns